# POST json array with php and ajax - PROBLEM

Tags: php, json, ajax

I can not understand how I can pass through scripts (below) an "action" variable and a "products" array created with php.

```
<?php
   $actionFile = "add";
   $products = array("Name product", "price", "sku", ....);
?>
<script>
    function uploadProducts() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("action", <?php echo json_encode($actionFile); ?>);
        formData.append("products", <?php echo json_encode($products); ?>);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './controllers/uploadProductsController.php',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                // Show image container
                //$("#loader").show();
                console.log("1");
            },
            success: function(response){
                //$('.response').empty();
                //$('.response').append(response);
                console.log("2");
                console.log(response);
            },
            complete: function(){
                // Hide image container
                //$("#loader").hide();
                console.log("3");
            }
        });            
    }
</script>
```

uploadProductsControlle.php (code below) I print the array as a single string and no as Array.

```
<?php
    include("../../functions.php");

    $action = $_POST['action'];
    $productsArr = $_POST['products'];
    $response = array();

    var_dump(json_encode($productsArr));  //ERROR THIS PRINT STRING

    foreach($productsArr as $product) {
        echo $product;
    }
    ?>
```

I need "products" as an array to do a cycle.
Thanks

Comment: Well that’s because you `json_encode` the array … which will result in a _string_ containing the JSON representation of that data structure.

Comment: what is <?php echo json_encode($actionFile); ?> ? where do you get the value of $actionFile ?

Comment: Hello, you could be clearer.

Comment: Why do you need to send data you apparently already _have_ in PHP (`$actionFile`, `$products`) on a round-trip via the client in the first place? Sounds like that should rather be put into the session to begin with.

Comment: $actionFile is a variable php $actionFile="add";

Comment: `formData.append` takes either a string or a blob as second parameter. With `<?php echo json_encode($products); ?>`, you are likely producing neither of those, but some sort of JavaScript array or object notation. So this value would need to be auto-converted into a string, which will result in the value being `[object Object]` or something like that - _literally_.

Comment: Hi, I modified my request with a simple example

Answer (score 0):

You should use json_decode function

```
$productsArr = json_decode($_POST['products']);
```

Comment: If you do var_dump, how the string looks like ?

Comment: How is the result of the code var_dump($productsArr); ?

Comment: the result "NULL"

Comment: So your problem probably is in ajax script. You should debug it firstly. Post data didn't reach to the PHP script.